# Split certain fields of a CSV file to spread above multiple lines while retaining the values of the non-split fields

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv, gawk

I have a `.csv` file like this:

```
IMSI,MSISDN,SUBCATEGY,EPCMMEHOST,EPCMMEREALM,EPCROAMSCH,PSROAMSCH,OINR,MSCNUMBER,VLRNUMBER,SGSNNUMBER,EPCAPNNAME,EPCAPNAMBRUP,EPCAPNAMBRDOWN,EPCAMBRUP,EPCAMBRDOWN,CHARGE,EPCCHARGCHRT
NAN,NAN,2,,,0,,0,,,,OLAP$DOLAP,200000000$2048000,400000000$2048000,200000000,400000000,5,5
```

I would like to split all fields that contain a `$` sign such that the part before that is kept on the original line and the part after it is transferred to a newly created line directly below, where the other fields of the file keep the same values as on the line where the splitting character was originally found. If several fields of a line contain the splitting delimiter, transfer the "second" parts of all fields to the same newly created line.

In the above example, the output should look as follows:

```
IMSI,MSISDN,SUBCATEGY,EPCMMEHOST,EPCMMEREALM,EPCROAMSCH,PSROAMSCH,OINR,MSCNUMBER,VLRNUMBER,SGSNNUMBER,EPCAPNNAME,EPCAPNAMBRUP,EPCAPNAMBRDOWN,EPCAMBRUP,EPCAMBRDOWN,CHARGE,EPCCHARGCHRT
NAN,NAN,2,,,0,,0,,,,OLAP,200000000,400000000,200000000,400000000,5,5
NAN,NAN,2,,,0,,0,,,,DOLAP,2048000,2048000,200000000,400000000,5,5
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. While your inclusion of sample input and output is commendable, it would be _really_ helpful if you also described the task at hand verbally; otherwise contributors will have to judge by their eyes what the difference is and infer what exactly you want to do.

Comment: I get that, if any column contains a $ separator, then the line is replicated with all such columns spread vertically. That definition is carefully phrased to cope with columns with three or more sub-fields. However, what happens if a column has two sub-fields, and another in the same line has three?

Comment: The title mentions 3 columns, but your sample output does not split `OLAP$DOLAP`. Is this a typo, or an additional rule?

Comment: And, show your own attempts on a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that the point mentioned by @Paul_Pedant was indeed a typo, and the `OLAP$DOLAP` field is also to be split. In this case, the following `awk` program (let's call it `splitfields.awk`) may work:

```c
#/usr/bin/awk -f
{
    copy=0;

    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
    {
        j=index($i,"$");
        if (j>0)
        {
            fields[i]=substr($i,j+1);
            $i=substr($i,1,j-1);
            copy=1
        }
        else fields[i]=$i;
    }
    print;

    if (copy==1)
    {
        for (i=1;i<NF;i++) printf("%s%s",fields[i],OFS);
        printf("%s%s",fields[NF],ORS)
    }
}
```

You would use it by calling

```
user@host~$ awk -F, -v OFS="," -f splitfields.awk input.csv
```

The script checks every field for the `$` sign and makes a copy of that field in an array `fields` for possible further use. If the `$` is found, the respective field of the *current* line is reduced to the part *before* the `$` while the corresponding entry in the `fields` array is filled with the part *after* the `$`.

After this check, the (possibly modified) current line is printed in any case. Additionally, if any one of the fields contained the `$` sign, a new line made up from the content of the `fields` array is printed in CSV formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{
    delete subFlds
    numSubFlds = 0
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        n = split($i,parts,/[$]/)
        for (subFldNr=1; subFldNr<=n; subFldNr++) {
            subFlds[i,subFldNr] = parts[subFldNr]
        }
        numSubFlds = (numSubFlds > n ? numSubFlds : n)
    }

    delete prev
    for (subFldNr=1; subFldNr<=numSubFlds; subFldNr++) {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            curr = ( (i,subFldNr) in subFlds ? subFlds[i,subFldNr] : prev[i] )
            printf "%s%s", curr, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)
            prev[i] = curr
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
IMSI,MSISDN,SUBCATEGY,EPCMMEHOST,EPCMMEREALM,EPCROAMSCH,PSROAMSCH,OINR,MSCNUMBER,VLRNUMBER,SGSNNUMBER,EPCAPNNAME,EPCAPNAMBRUP,EPCAPNAMBRDOWN,EPCAMBRUP,EPCAMBRDOWN,CHARGE,EPCCHARGCHRT
NAN,NAN,2,,,0,,0,,,,OLAP,200000000,400000000,200000000,400000000,5,5
NAN,NAN,2,,,0,,0,,,,DOLAP,2048000,2048000,200000000,400000000,5,5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{split("",q);for(i=j=1;i<=NF;i++){if(split($i,a,/\$/)>1){j++;$i=a[1];q[i]=a[2]}}print;if(j>1){for(i in q)$i=q[i];print}}' file
```

Or, expanded:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{
  split("", q)       # clear the q array; delete q is non-standard
  for(i = j = 1; i <= NF; i++){
    if(split($i, a, /\$/) > 1){  # if the field contains a $
       j++                # increase the cnt of fields with a $
       $i = a[1]          # set the field to the part before the $
       q[i] = a[2]        # save the part after the $ in the q array
    }
  }
  print                   # print the line with the parts before $
  if(j > 1){              # if any field had a $
     for(i in q)          # for each field which had a $
       $i = q[i]          # replace it with the part after $  
     print                # re-print the line with the parts after $
  }
}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ perl -F, -lane '$,=",";
    print,next unless /\$/;
    for(@F) {
      my @e = split /\$/;
      push @A, @e ? $e[0] : $_;
      push @B, @e ? $e[1] : $_;
    }
    print splice @$_ for \(@A, @B);
'  file.csv
```

**brief working:**

only lines that have a literal $ we loop over the fields and split a field into two that has a $ in it.

Then  populate the two arrays A and B

Finally print and empty out the arrays A B for next record.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, that some fields are "double" variant fields separated by `$` and you just want two copies of those lines with the first line containing the first variant and the second line with the second variant....

```
awk '{v1=$0; gsub(/\$[^,]+/,""); gsub (/,[^,]+\$/,",",v1); print $0; if (v1!=$0) print v1}' file1

IMSI,MSISDN,SUBCATEGY,EPCMMEHOST,EPCMMEREALM,EPCROAMSCH,PSROAMSCH,OINR,MSCNUMBER,VLRNUMBER,SGSNNUMBER,EPCAPNNAME,EPCAPNAMBRUP,EPCAPNAMBRDOWN,EPCAMBRUP,EPCAMBRDOWN,CHARGE,EPCCHARGCHRT
NAN,NAN,2,,,0,,0,,,,OLAP,200000000,400000000,200000000,400000000,5,5
NAN,NAN,2,,,0,,0,,,,DOLAP,2048000,2048000,200000000,400000000,5,5
```